# Unresolved dependency when Scalatest used with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

My dependencies in build.sbt is as follows

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"    
ibraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0" %"provided" ,
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0" %"provided" ,
      "org.scalatest" %%"scalatest" % "2.0" %"test"
 }
```

when i build project i got below error

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.11;2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:2.0 
[warn]        +- transformer:transformer_2.11:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.11;2.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
```

though it work fine if i remove the **provided** keyword from spark dependencies
and also work if i use 3.0 version of scalatest but i need to use 2.0 version only

can someone help how could i resolve this issue?

Comment: you should be using `"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.0" % "test"` instead of `"org.scalatest" %%"scalatest" % "2.0" %"test"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error reason: "scalatest" version "2.0" absent in Maven repository:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.scalatest%22%20AND%20a%3A%22scalatest_2.11%22

Please try existed, for example "2.2.0".
Guess, keyword "provided" is not related to error.

Comment: 2.2.0 version is working but i find 2.0 version also and that is build on scala 2.10 version may be that is the reason of conflict as i am using scala 2.11 version